# how to acces list elements based on condition in r

Tags: r, list

This sseems me very simple, however I can not get good graps on it. Lets say I have list like this:

`my_list=list(integer(0),c(4,3,3),integer(0),integer(0),c(5,2,5),integer(0))`

I used `integer(0)` to make it similar to my original data but any condition here is applicable. Now i want to extract from my list only those elements that are NOT `integer(0)` making new 2-element list like this:

`list_I_try_to_make=list(c(4,3,3),c(5,2,5))`

I know how to do this for data frame but I am not sure how to correctly adress each element of list. I tried `lapply` with condition for each element but this simply returns me new list with same length where each element is an answer (if `length>0` it only returns `TRUE/FALSE`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `purrr` package which is very convenient when working with lists.

```
library(purrr)

keep(my_list, function(x) length(x) > 0)
```

Comment: you can use the ~ shorthand instead of writing function, like this:

keep(my_list, ~ length(.x) > 0)

when using the tilde-shorthand, the (only) function argument is always ".x".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lengths`

```
my_list[lengths(my_list) > 0]
[[1]]
[1] 4 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution :

`my_list[ !unlist(lapply(my_list,identical,integer(0))) ]`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
my_filter=unlist(lapply(my_list,length))>0
my_list[my_filter]
[[1]]
[1] 4 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filter`:

```
my_list <- list(integer(0),c(4,3,3),integer(0),integer(0),c(5,2,5),integer(0))
Filter(function(x) length(x)>0, my_list)
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 3 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 2 5
```